# Jerky scrolling with Images in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, sdwebimage

So I have been reading lots of solutions to this problem and it seems no matter what I do, I am still getting jerky scrolling in my UITableView when there are images present in my cells.

Here is a little info on how I am generating my cells.

I am calculating heights for the cells and cacheing the heights in height for row at index path

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let height = cachedHeights[indexPath.row] {
        return height
    } else {
        let post = dataSource.items[indexPath.row]
        var CellClass = FeedTableViewCell.self

        if let RegisteredCellClass = cells[post.reusableIdentifier] {
            CellClass = RegisteredCellClass
        }

        cachedHeights[indexPath.row] = CellClass.height(post)

        return CellClass.height(post)
    }
}
```

I have verified that the actual and calculated sizes are the same.

When configuring the cell in cell for row at indexpath, I setup all the elements and load the images asynchronously with SDWebImage

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let post = dataSource.items[indexPath.row]
        var wallCell: FeedTableViewCell?

        if let registeredCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: post.reusableIdentifier) as? FeedTableViewCell {
            wallCell = registeredCell
            if let postCell = wallCell as? FeedTableViewPostCell {
                postCell.informationDelegete = self
                postCell.actionDelegate = self
            }
        }

        guard let cell = wallCell else { return FeedTableViewPostCell() }

        cell.configureCell(post)
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Configure cell calls the method on the cell that populates the element with the post data.  There is a sub view called mediaview that handles the images.  If there are images int he post they are configured in that view like so.

```
for (index, element) in media.enumerated() where index < 3 {
    addSubview(viewsArray[index])
    viewsArray[index].setImage(with: element.source, placeholderImage: nil)
}
```

I read something about SDWebImage causing issues in it's default UIImageView extension so I wrote my own and this is the code for that.

```
func setImage(with url: URL?, placeholderImage: UIImage?){
    if let placeholder = placeholderImage{
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.image = placeholder
        })
    }

    SDWebImageManager.shared().loadImage(with: url, options: [SDWebImageOptions.cacheMemoryOnly, SDWebImageOptions.scaleDownLargeImages], progress: nil, completed: {(image, data, error, cacheType, finished, url) in
        if finished {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.alpha = 0
                UIView.transition(with: self, duration: 0.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.image = image
                    self.alpha = 1
                }, completion: nil)
            })
        }

    })
}
```

If I comment out the block in mediaview that sets the image, my scrolling is perfectly smooth so I know it's not another portion of the cell generation.  My understanding was that the asynchronous loading should alleviate the scrolling lag but I have attempted just about everything to no avail.  Any help or insights on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running the profiler?

Comment: @Alexander I have run the core animation profiler and I see the frames dropping to about 55 FPS when scrolling.  Not a huge drop but there is a noticeable pause when an image cell loads

Comment: are you caching images? Also what calls setImage?

Comment: Yes images are cached using SDWebImages caching mechanism. setImage is called on the media view sub view of the cell when configuring the cell in cellForRowAt.